# more than one callback url for twitter app (localhost and live site)?

Tags: passport.js, passport-twitter

Can i set the more than one call back urls in twitter app just like google app . I have done the twitter authuntication through `require('passport-twitter').Strategy;`
this allow me only one url . can i set it to two urls one for localhost and one for live site e.g

```
 callbackURL: "site.com/auth/twitter/callback",
```

and

```
callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback"
```

[image]

google allow more than one

Comment: I'm not sure, but seems twitter only accepts 1 callback URL. In this case, I believe you have to create two applicatons (on twitter) and manage those in you app using ENV variables. (e.g. env = 'production')

Answer (score 0):

I don't know passport.js but the Twitter "oauth/request_token" endpoint allows you to pass an "oauth_callback" parameter with the callback URL. Check this link: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token

Hope this helps! ;)